# arXiv submission \mathbb problem with mtpro2

Tags: mtpro, blackboard, mathbb, mtpro2

**Update:** Thank you for comments and warnings! I contacted arXiv support to be sure, and you are **not allowed** to use mtpro2.

I am trying to make a submission to arXiv, and I am using mtpro2 for my symbols.
I included all the files like .map .sty .tfm etc.

Processing succeeds, however, all of my \mathbb{} symbols are printed as regular letters.
What could be the reason? I would really appreciate it if someone could help me to identify the issue. I do not know what I need to provide.

Below I attached an example that compiles well on my end, but fails on arXiv:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}    
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}  

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,mtphrd]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,   
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=red,    
    citecolor=blue
}

\def\dbR{\mathbb{R}}
\def\dbV{\mathbb{V}}

\begin{document}

\title{\bf Small Example}

\maketitle




\begin{abstract}
  To show symbols:
  \begin{equation*}
    \label{setvalued}
    \dbV: [0, T]\times \dbR^d \to 2^{\dbR^m}.
  \end{equation*}
  That is, for each $(t,x)\in [0, T]\times \dbR^d$,
\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```

When I compile:

[image: When I compile]

When arXiv compiles:
[image: When arXiv compiles]

Comment: please show a small complete document which shows the problem. You posted some code which will give errors due to missing `}` but does not typeset anything or demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for prompt response. I attached screenshots. I hope this helps to identify, please let me know if anything else I can provide. (I will prepare a small document, but the problem is when arXiv compiles it)

Comment: mtphrd as far as I can see is the times-like mathbb which requitres the commercial mathtime fonts which arxiv won't have, you could presumably use the other set which is in  the lite free subset (I don't actually have either)

Comment: note `\bf` hasn't been defined by default in latex for 30 years and `ptm` family deprecated for almost as long, you may find it easier to use `newtxtext,newtxmath` for a totally free times compatible math and text setup.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I unfortunately don't know about their current status, but I found ptm nicer than newtxtext. I actually tried newtxtext,newtxmath before paying for mtpro2, but didn't like it.

Comment: Although I couldn't solve my problem, I found that a workaround is to add the 'amsbb' option, which then allows the use of AMS symbols for the \mathbb command.

Comment: paying for mtpro is fine for your documents on your machine but you can't use the commercial part of mtpro at arxiv as they need to process the document on their servers with fonts for which they have a licence, so it's not a matter of which one looks best it's which ones  are installed on the remote system.

Comment: As far as I understand, I am allowed to use mtpro. arXiv is able to process style files, and mtpro license allows for me to share the document. Thank you for the warning.

Comment: you can share a pdf document with the fonts embedded but I don't think you have a licence that allows arxiv to run latex using the fonts (even if technically you could make it work)

Comment: https://info.arxiv.org/help/faq/freefonts.html

Comment: @Jo' You bought a license of MTPro2, so you're allowed to use them for any purpose covered in the license. But this doesn't include passing the fonts to anybody. In order to process your document, arXiv should have bought and installed MTPro2, which I think is unlikely.